# dos countdowns en un solo html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

Tengo un `countdown` funcionando en mi `html`, pero necesito que justo después de terminar, inicie una nueva cuenta regresiva con un tiempo diferente en el mismo `countdown`, este es el `js`

```js
$(function (){

function countdown() {

var now = new Date();
var eventDate = new Date('Nov 03, 2017 10:18:40');
var currentTime = now.getTime();
var evenTime = eventDate.getTime();

if(eventDate<=currentTime){
    clearInterval(setTimeout);
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";

}

var remTime = evenTime - currentTime;

var sec = Math.floor(remTime / 1000);
var min = Math.floor(sec / 60);
var hur = Math.floor(min / 60);
var day = Math.floor(hur / 24);

 hur %= 24;
 min %= 60;
 sec %= 60;

hur = (hur < 10) ? "0" + hur : hur;
min = (min < 10) ? "0" + min : min;
sec = (sec < 10) ? "0" + sec : sec;

$('.seconds').text(sec);
$('.minutes').text(min);
$('.hours').text(hur);
$('.days').text(day);

setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
}

countdown({elapse: true});



});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="countdown-section col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                    <div id="countdown">
                        <ul class="countdown">
                        <h2 class="countheader">Round Starts in</h2>
                        <li> <span class="days">00</span>
                        <p class="days_ref">days</p>
                        </li>
                        <li class="seperator">.</li>
                        <li> <span class="hours">00</span>
                        <p class="hours_ref">hours</p>
                        </li>
                        <li class="seperator">:</li>
                        <li> <span class="minutes">00</span>
                        <p class="minutes_ref">minutes</p>
                        </li>
                        <li class="seperator">:</li>
                        <li> <span class="seconds">00</span>
                        <p class="seconds_ref">seconds</p>
                        </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: En tu [anterior pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/114411/78) recibiste una respuesta y la aceptaste. ¿Qué problema tienes con este código?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entiendo que buscas que de forma automática se inicie el segundo contador.

Puedes cambiar la variable **eventDate** por un tipo Array para almacenar varias fechas y recorrerlas con una variable **x = 0** (fuera de la función) que sume +1 cada vez que detecte que la fecha ya expiró.

Tomar en cuenta que el Array será recorrido en el orden que lo declaraste y no buscará la fecha mas próxima a expirar.

```
var eventDate = [
            new Date('Nov 04, 2017 16:15:00'),
            new Date('Nov 04, 2017 16:20:00'),
            new Date('Nov 04, 2017 16:25:00')
        ];
```

El código quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
$(function (){
    var x = 0;
    function countdown() {            
        var now = new Date();
        var currentTime = now.getTime();

        var eventDate = [
            new Date('Nov 04, 2017 16:15:00'),
            new Date('Nov 04, 2017 16:20:00'),
            new Date('Nov 04, 2017 16:25:00')
        ];

        if(eventDate[x].getTime() <= currentTime){
            if ( x < eventDate.length - 1) {
                x++;
                countdown();
            } else{
                document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
            }
        } else{
            var remTime = eventDate[x].getTime() - currentTime;

            var sec = Math.floor(remTime / 1000);
            var min = Math.floor(sec / 60);
            var hur = Math.floor(min / 60);
            var day = Math.floor(hur / 24);

            hur %= 24;
            min %= 60;
            sec %= 60;

            hur = (hur < 10) ? "0" + hur : hur;
            min = (min < 10) ? "0" + min : min;
            sec = (sec < 10) ? "0" + sec : sec;

            $('.seconds').text(sec);
            $('.minutes').text(min);
            $('.hours').text(hur);
            $('.days').text(day);

            setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
        }
    }
    countdown();
});
```

Comment: Funciono perfecto, muchas gracias